# Why Aren't Patent Expirations Listed for USPTO Gazette Vol. 1454 No. 2?

Tags: uspto, usa, expired-patent, fees, maintenance-fee

Reviewing 300+ issues of the *Official Gazette Of The United States Patent And Trademark Office*, from 2014 to present I noticed that only one issue —  [Vol. 1454 No. 2, from September 11th, 2018](https://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/com/sol/og/2018/week37/TOC.htm#ref7)  — lacks the section 'Notice of Expiration of Patents Due to Failure to Pay Maintenance Fee'.

Was there something special about this week or is it an inadvertent omission?

If it is an error, where and how would the notice be corrected?

I didn't see it mentioned in the adjacent or near following issues.  But admittedly, I don't really know what to look for.

Comment: It seems very strange since a typical week has so many expired patents listed